# OsX 10.12.6 WebServer gives 500 error: "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, macos, apache, webserver

I have a local development server that was working just fine. I recently updated to OsX 10.12, and now the configuration is all screwed up. When I try to run a python file located in the cgi-bin I get a "500 internal error".
The Command

> tail /var/log/apache2/error_log

gives

> [cgi:error] [pid 62036] [client ::1:55162] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/PuMA/display_new_viruses.py' failed: /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/PuMA/display_new_viruses.py, referer: http://localhost/puma/

However,

> cd /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/PuMA
>   ls

returns

> display_new_viruses.py

Finally,

> ls -l display_new_viruses.py

returns

> -rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel  2675 Aug 16  2016 display_new_viruses.py

Any ideas what may be going on?

thanks!

Comment: What's the shebang line in display_new_viruses.py? Does it point to a python interpreter that isn't there anymore?

Comment: that turned out to be the problem! Thanks so much! Seems like an odd error?